# Start a different program instead of the desktop manager

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, kiosk

I am trying to build a computer-based lighting console for a charity organization, and I have everything setup using QLC+ and Ubuntu, but I want to set it so that once the volunteers log in, it does not load the desktop, rather it goes straight into QLC+, and even if closed does not load the desktop. There are a number of reasons for that, the first is security. Since this organization is 100% volunteer run, I don't want anyone messing with the OS once I have everything configured.  The second reason is to reduce overhead, but that isn't as important to me as the security aspect.

I know in Windows, I could simply create a batch script that starts QLC+, and modify the registry entry at: `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\Shell` to point to the batch file instead of `explorer.exe`, but I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu will work better for this project than Windows will; even though QLC+ is cross platform.

Here's what I have so far in my attempts to do this on my own:

1. I can put a new startup entry in Ubuntu's Startup Applications Preferences with the command: `qlcplus --open %f`, and it opens QLC+ along with the desktop manager.
2. I have tried replacing the ubuntu.desktop file in `/usr/share/xsessions` with a file containing the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=qlcplus --open %f
   Terminal=false
   Name=WSCC Lighting Console
   ```

When I start the computer with that configuration, it logs in with the GUI, but just sits and doesn't load QLC+.

3. Since when I open a terminal session in that state and run `startx`, it opens just QLC+ at this point, I tried modifying the `ubuntu.desktop` file to contain the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=startx
   Terminal=false
   Name=WSCC Lighting Console
   ```

It seems like I am almost there, but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

OK, although I didn't accomplish my goal exactly the way that I was looking for, but after doing some research I did find a way of doing this for the specific application that I am looking for.  It appears that QLC+ happens to have a kiosk mode built into the Linux version, so the syntax that I need to run in my auto start entry is:

```
qlcplus --kiosk --fullscreen --open workspace.qxw
```

I would still be interested in knowing how I could have gone about doing it the way I had been asking, since I may run into something similar in the future, so if anyone has a way of doing it as phrased in the question, I would still love to hear it for learning's sake.